# Magento configuration _beforeSave not working on website scope

Tags: system-configuration

I am trying to validate my configuration before save but it does not work on website scope.

It works if i choose default config scope.

Here is my code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <banktransfer>
                    <fields>
                        <showinfrontend translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled On Front-End</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </showinfrontend>
                        <partpayment translate="label">
                        <label>Partpayment Method</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>bankpayment/partpayment</source_model>
                        <backend_model>bankpayment/system_config_backend_validatepayment</backend_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </partpayment>
                    </fields>
                </banktransfer>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Model file is as below.

```
    <?php
class Kgn_Bankpayment_Model_System_Config_Backend_Validatepayment extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
         echo "<pre/>";print_r(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost());exit;

        $value = $this->getValue();
        $totalpartCollection = Mage::getModel('pdftemplate/totalpart')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('payment_id','banktransfer');
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $table = $resource->getTableName('pdftemplate/totalpart');
        foreach($totalpartCollection as $totalpart){
            $id = $totalpart->getId();
            if($value == $id){
                $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET status = 1,is_default=1 WHERE totalpartrule_id = "
             . (int)$id;
             $writeConnection->query($query);
            }else{
                $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET status = 2,is_default=0 WHERE totalpartrule_id = ". (int)$id;
                $writeConnection->query($query);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.

But it is strange when i choose website or store view scope and only one of checkbox checked near form field then it is not working if i uncheck all the checkbox and save then it is working. If anyone know how this is actually working please write note here for understand.

[Here Is Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/un3aEIoChayd)